# What are the reasons and benefits of overriding toString() for string representation of an object?

Tags: java, class, object, tostring

When we need a String representation of an object, we can override the `toString()` method. However, what are the real benefits and reasons for overriding `toString()` when we can just define a new method to return the string?

Please see example below:

```
class One
{
    private String name;
    public One(String _name)
    {
        name = _name;
    }

    @Override public String toString()
    {
        return name;
    }       
}

class Two
{
    private String name;
    public Two(String _name)
    {
        name = _name;
    }

    public String printMyClass() //Self-defined to print class details
    {
        return name;
    }       
}
```

In the above example, `printMyClass()` which is self-defined seemed to does the same thing as `toString()`.

**So my question is:** Why do we still use `toString()` ?

Comment: For continuity. Example - when a developer needs to get a String representation of your object, then the first thing he uses is the toString().

Comment: Also, if I recall correctly, if you print an object directly in Java (ie. `System.out.println(myObject);` ) it would call your toString() method rather than printing HashCode. I could be wrong.

Comment: Btw, I have a loose policy of "toString() for human-readable representation, another method for machine-parseable."  So I may have for instance a `toString()` that I intend to read in a debugger, and a `toJsonString()` for when I want to serialize it (well, in real life I'd probably use jackson or some other library to json-ify it for me, but you get the point).

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor It is a different question, because I am asking on the basis of comparing it with a self-defined method to return the string.

Comment: user3437460, yes, and if your reason for defining some other method that returns a string isn't the same reason for the toString method, then you're probably justified in writing a new method (e.g., @yshavit's toJsonString() method), but if it is the same reason, then you should just override Object#toString().

Answer (score 5):

The main benefits are that libraries expect this behaviour and use it.

If for example you log `"funcX called with ("+param1+", "+param2+")"` then `toString()` will automatically be called for you.

Additionally this means that you always know that the `toString()` method is available (since it is defined in  so you can call it on every object without needing to worry about whether it is present or not.

A better question for you is why not use it? It's provided for you so why do you not want to use it?

Answer (score 3):

Easy conversion to String type that is used in String concatenation with + operator.

The benefit is that you don't have to write `printMyClass()` multiple times.

This is shorter

```
obj1 + " " + obj2
```

than this

```
obj1.printMyClass() + " " + obj2.printMyClass()
```

I do sometimes use it to help debugger show more readable output, but that's a little eccentric.

Comment: Is that the only benefit from technical point of view (meaning that I am not looking at "having it as a good practice..etc")? Thanks for answering!

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I got it now. Do you mind showing an example of using String concatenation with + operator on toString() ? Is this what you guys mean ? --> System.out.println(obj1 + obj2);

Comment: Ah, as I suspected, it needs to be concatenated with a String and cannot be concatenated by obj1 + obj2. +1 from me. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Because `toString` is used by *all other* Java code to get a `String` representation of the `Object`.

Consider, for example, parametrised logging in SLF4j, here we use a format `String` and arguments to create a logging statement:

```
log.info("User {} has just logged in.", user);
```

The logging library will, if the logging level is low enough, take the format `String` and call `toString` on `user` in order to get the final logging message.

This is just one example of something that can generally be called a "call back". Since `toString` is part of the Java API **many** libraries use it to convert an `Object` to `String. Doing the same, for example, deferred evaluation logging, would have required an`interface` and an anonymous class (pre Java 8) which is very messy.

In the most simple example consider `String` concatenation and implicit `String` conversion:

```
final String string = "User is " + user;
```

Without the `toString` method how would this even be possible?